# Override custom module template

Tags: 7, theming

I created a custom module with its own template file to display the content with the following code.

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'theme_mymodule_list' => [
      'template' => 'templates/list_mymodule',
      // name of the template file, minus the '.tpl.php'

      // these are the template variables that will available to your template
      'variables' => [
        'myvar1' => NULL,
      ],
    ],

  ];
}
```

With the code above I'm able to get the template from the module directory (sites/all/modules/mymodule/templates/list_mymodule.tpl.php), but now I decided to make a theme for the site, and I want to override the custom module template file with the usual approach of copying-pasting the file into the theme and clear the cache.

How do I override the template used from a custom module from a theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is something that Drupal core already does. Take as example the Node module; it defines its own template file ([node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7.x)) that is then overridden from themes, such as the Bartik theme, with their own template file (in the case of the Bartik theme, with [templates/node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes%21bartik%21templates%21node.tpl.php/7.x)).

What is wrong in your implementation of `hook_theme()` is the name you give to the template file. Despite what it could seem, the *template* key doesn't allow to give the template name an arbitrary name; the name must match the theme name you are using, in your case mymodule_list. You can replace the underscores in the theme name with hyphens, but that is the only change you could do.

See [Override template files based on template filename as well as hook name](https://www.drupal.org/node/342350), where the user suggesting the change says:

> Turns out the template file name needs to exactly match the array key used in `hook_theme()` (with the exception of dashes and underscores). In the case of my example, the template value would need to be **my_abc_index** and the file name **my-abc-index.tpl.php**. Failure to do so will result in an un-overridable template.

(I slightly changed formatting, and the spelling of a word.)

Also, as you see in the code used from Drupal core, the *theme_* prefix in the the theme name is not necessary.

```
function node_theme() {
  return array(
    'node' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'node',
    ),
    'node_search_admin' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
    'node_add_list' => array(
      'variables' => array('content' => NULL),
      'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
    ),
    'node_preview' => array(
      'variables' => array('node' => NULL),
      'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
    ),
    'node_admin_overview' => array(
      'variables' => array('name' => NULL, 'type' => NULL),
      'file' => 'content_types.inc',
    ),
    'node_recent_block' => array(
      'variables' => array('nodes' => NULL),
    ),
    'node_recent_content' => array(
      'variables' => array('node' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override tpl files defined in modules inside your active theme (under the templates directory). But Drupal will look for a file name using the defined theme key name and not the defined template file.

In your case, you should create a `theme_mymodule_list.tpl.php` file within your theme. Maybe a good practice to name your template file the same as your theme definition.